# Asterisk loses connection SQL server

Tags: sql-server, centos, odbc, asterisk

i have asterisk Core and i have connected this to sql server with odbc and using func_odbc .
this func odbc executing stored procedure there is only 1 value return but sometimes not always i get this

> [Feb 16 12:07:12] WARNING[16437]: func_odbc.c:191 generic_execute: SQL
>   Execute returned an error -1: 24000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid
>   cursor state (41) [Feb 16 12:07:12] WARNING[16437]: func_odbc.c:199
>   generic_execute: SQL Exec Direct failed (-1)![Exec dbo.Main_Dest
>   @bnumb = ‘XXXXXXXXX’] [Feb 16 12:07:12] WARNING[16437]: res_odbc.c:604
>   ast_odbc_direct_execute: SQL Execute error! Verifying connection to
>   MSSQL [MSSQL]…

so i have searched too many solutions but there is nothing about sql server i have tried some changes in db and in odbc.conf timeouts and stuff but it’s not working to me but mby there is some timeout time that must be plz help me solve this problem

here is my

> res_odbc.conf:

```
Hide   Copy Code
dsn =>MSSQL
username =>sa
password =>******!
polling=> no
limit => 1
pre-connect => yes
idlecheck => 300
negative_connection_cache => 100
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the SQL, not the connection. Notice the error states: `SQL Execute returned an error -1: 24000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid cursor state (41)`. Sounds like you're using a `CURSOR` and it's being used incorrectly.

Comment: i am using Func_odbc for executing commands in func_odbc i have Exec dbo.Main_Dest @bnumb =(asterisk giving me number) soo in sql i have stored procedure Main_dest with many selects on the end it will return 1 answear only

Comment: Check your sql version manual. Maybe you should use commit after stored proc or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try decrease idle check timer and put in some valuable sql for check(for example "select 1 from your_main_table limit 1")

Also it is not so nice idea do negative cache of 100. That mean "not try reconnect if failed once, at least 100 sec".

Comment: thnx for comment here is thee thing that i can have for example 10 or more simultaneous calls so each call is executing this procedure in db and getting information

Comment: Try connection pooling then.

Comment: you mean polling=> yes?

Comment: I don't know where you have finded that settings. in res_odbc it is max_connections => 20 option.

Comment: https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/configs/samples/res_odbc.conf.sample

Comment: You always can check source. There is no option "polling", but you can see it WAS option "pooling" which now not supported(just ctrl-F via source code) https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/res/res_odbc.c

Comment: `enabled => yes
dsn =>MSSQL
username =>asterisk
password =>******
limit => 20
forcecommit => yes
pre-connect => yes
idlecheck => 300
sanitysql => select 1` changed my res odbc conf and look now my odbc settings when i press `odbc show all ` ` Last connection attempt: 1970-01-01 04:00:00
  Pooled: No
  Connected: Yes`

Comment: why it isn't showing me Number of active connections i tried max connections too but there is nothing